# If and would construction

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> If I do all this, I would have such a story to tell.

Is this sentence wrong? I've searched it up and it's wrong according to grammar guides -- but I've seen it so often. The *would* is supposed to show how the event is:

1. Possible
2. Ambitious but somewhat probably and not unlikely

Comment: Look at your tenses. If I do... I ____ have. If I did... I ___ have. Not taking into account the more formal constructions.

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? I mean, you've already given the descriptivist answer ("I've seen it so often") and the prescriptivist answer ("it's wrong according to grammar guides"); what else is there?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two choices:

If I do all this, I will have such a story to tell.

If I did all this, I would have such a story to tell.

In the first case you have what could be called "a provisional intention". If I *do* this, such and such *will* happen. The sentence is the kind you might expect after someone has already expressed such an intention and is looking at the likely result. In the second sentence, the situation is more like a speculation, or a hypothesis, where someone has not decided how to proceed and is going through the choices. I don't know if, strictly speaking, it's subjunctive grammar, where you are using the past tense ("did") to denote the hypothetical present or the hypothetical future, but it's certainly the subjunctive mood.

At any rate, to make both halves of the sentence match, you'd pick one of the two pairings: do/will or did/would have.

Comment: There are forms of protasis that begin "If I were to do X" and "If I had done X," as well. It's a scary and complicated area, with subtle shades of meaning associated with each option. In particular, the seemingly simple "If I did X" option is trickier than it may at first appear. For example, it seems to me that O. J. Simpson's book title _If I Did It_ would make more sense if the book were premised on the author's inability to remember whether he "did it" or not, than if the author were offering a hypothetical discussion of what his motives and methods would have been _If I Had Done It_.

Answer (score 0):

Colloquially speaking, you could say "if I would do all this, I would have such a story to tell", which can make sense and be grammatically acceptable for as long as what is conveyed is "If I was willing to do all this, I would have such a story to tell".

Answer (score 0):

The more correct way of wording this would be by following the rules of modal verbs that are used to convey likelihood, possibility, permission etc.

which would look like this:
If I do all this, I would have such a story to tell.